# How perform Deconvolution (transposed convolution) in Theano/ Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, theano, keras

I am trying to perform deconvolution or transposed convolution using Theano/ Keras as described in [1].

I have acquired the weights of a given layer by the following code:

```
W = self[layer].get_weights() # 'layer' is the layer of interest
```

I have used the following code to deconv the Image by the weights acquired:

```
X = K.deconv2d(X, theano.tensor.as_tensor_variable(W[0]), self[layer].input_shape)
print X
```

Where `X` is the input image of dimension `[9,3,32,32]`. The output I am getting is as follows:

```
AbstractConv2d_gradInputs{border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), filter_flip=True, imshp=(None, 3, 32, 32), kshp=(None, None, None, None), filter_dilation=(1, 1)}.0
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, you are just printing the symbolic representation, as Theano is a symbolic computation library.

Comment: Yes, I got it corrected. Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: can you re-type the link that you mentioned above since it is not in your post please?